# Question about how to run code the same on all screens in an app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have written code to check the status of a network connection. I used the **Reachability** library.

```
let reachability = Reachability()!

reachability.whenReachable = { reachability in
            if reachability.connection == .wifi {
                print("Reachable via WiFi")
                CustomActivityIndicator.shared.hide(uiView: self.view)
            } else {
                print("Reachable via Cellular")
                CustomActivityIndicator.shared.hide(uiView: self.view)
            }
        }

        reachability.whenUnreachable = { _ in
            print("Not reachable")

            CustomActivityIndicator.shared.show(uiView: self.view, labelText: "Not reachable", backgroundColor: self.color, textColor: .white, animated: false, duration: 0)
        }

        do {
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }
```

I also wrote code that notifies the user via the `CustomActivityIndicator` when the network is disconnected and hides the `CustomActivityIndicator` when reconnected.

Where should I put the code so that it works on all screens of the app?

Comment: You should not use Reachability at all.

Comment: Just create a singleton and display the view in `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow()`

Comment: @matt Why shouldn't Reachability be used at all?

Comment: @lavta3 Because that's what Apple says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is: create a base view controller and inherit all your view controllers from the BaseViewController and wrote the common code i.e Reachability in this context in that base class.